# I know this is pretty primitive but i want to make this function work in a shorter in more efficient manner

Tags: python

> instructions = 
>   Given an int array length 2, return True if it contains a 2 or a 3.

```
  def has23(nums):
    if nums[0] == 2 or nums[0]== 3 :
      return True 
    elif nums[1] == 2 or nums[1]==3 :
      return True 
    else:
      return False
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
def has23(nums):
    return 2 in nums or 3 in nums
```

Answer (score 3):

Some performance of the answers:

```
def has23(nums):
    if '3' in str(nums) or '2' in str(nums):
        return True
    else:
        return False
%timeit has23([1,3])
# 415 ns ± 14.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

def has23(nums):
    return 2 in nums or 3 in nums
%timeit has23([1,3])
# 138 ns ± 7.77 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

def has23(nums):
    return set(nums) & {2, 3}
%timeit has23([1,3])
# 340 ns ± 4.01 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

I am personally a fan of @John Anderson's answer, as it's concise and fast with small arrays as OP specified.

P.S. as suggested by @UltraInstinct

```
def has23(nums):
    for x in nums:
        if x in (2,3):
            return True
    return False
%timeit has23([1,3])
# 171 ns ± 1.82 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: The benefit of using set operation is that it's highly scalable. Try testing if `nums` has any of 1000 given numbers rather than 2, for example, and the difference in average time complexity would show.

Comment: @blhsing I agree. Set would be the first thing I'd come to when scaling. The OP specified the array has a length of 2, with this scale an `in` operator is enough though.

Comment: Yup. There's some overhead in initializing a set, which isn't worth the time if the size is small.

Comment: Nitpick: the first `has23` implementation should have `return False` outside the loop. Can you re-run after fixing it? Thanks!

Comment: @UltraInstinct Thanks for the pick. I just tried that, the performance is a bit worse, as the test case [1,3] is the worst scenario. I also tried false cases such as [1,4], it actually makes no difference to [1,3].

Answer (score 1):

I created your solution with example and explanation. There are 2 functions, one to check single match the other to check all matches overall.

```
# Function to check if the value is inside the array
def isMatch(value, myList):
    # Set the value to False by default
    result = False
    # Check if the value is inside the array
    if value in myList:
        # Set the result to True
        result = True
    # Return the result for that match term
    return result

# Function to check every matches terms
def checkIfIsMatch(listOfMatches, listOfValues):
    # Return True is there is any match
    return any(isMatch(value, listOfValues) for value in listOfMatches)

# List of values to check inside array
listOfMatches = [2,3]

# Example array 1
listOfValues1 = [5,3]
# Store the result into a variable
result1 = checkIfIsMatch(listOfMatches, listOfValues1)
# Print example 1
print result1
# Output: True

listOfValues2 = [5,7]
# Store the result into a variable
result2 = checkIfIsMatch(listOfMatches, listOfValues2)
# Print example 2
print result2
# Output: False
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try writing it this way:

```
def has23(nums):
    for x in nums:
        if x in (2,3):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

or

```
    if nums[0] in (2,3) or nums[1] in (2,3):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

/ogs

Answer (score 0):

```
def has23(nums):
    if '3' in str(nums) or '2' in str(nums):
        return true
    else:
        return false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set intersection:

```
def has23(nums):
    return set(nums) & {2, 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a *filtered list* that only will hold `2` or `3` and test that, if `any(filtered_list)` means it contains a `2` or `3` and `True` will be returned if not `False`

```
def has23(num):
    return any([*filter(lambda x: x == '2' or x == '3', str(num))])

print(has23(21)) # => True
print(has23(83)) # => True
print(has23(54)) # => False
```